# Unable to remove System.Diagnostics & Microsoft Logging dlls

Tags: c#, dll, sdk, okta

I am in the process to switch to Application Insights for Diagnostics/Logging purpose. Currently, I have System.Diagnostics/Microsoft Logging for the same.I am trying to remove these dlls but the issue is these dlls are two of the dependencies of Okta SDK [image]

[image]

Any way to get this removed without breaking the existing functionality?

Comment: The error is pretty clear - you have another package that depends on Microsoft.Extensions.Logging. So no, as long as that package is in the dependency path of any of your referenced packages, it'll get resolved/restored by nuget/msbuild.